# Is it okay for me to improve my friend's questions through editing?

Tags: discussion, edits, reputation

My friend doesn't know much English. I'm always helping him by writing his applications, letters, etc. Now on Stack Overflow he posted 2 questions, which made no sense whatsoever, getting no response from users. He told me his problem in our local language, then I edited his question accordingly. After that he got some answers and his problem was solved.

I got 4 points for editing his two questions. Now I feel like this will not stop since his problems are not going away soon, and every programmer once in a while needs Stack Overflow.

And I can't post his questions for him, since he has his own account and must deserve upvotes/downvotes for helping/annoying other similar users respectively.

Is it ok for me to help him like this? My sole intention is to help him get his problems solved, not earning those 2 points every time he will ask me to edit his posts. I know after 2k mark I won't get those 2 points but I'm below 2k currently.

Comment: I think it's more appropriate if you send him the "fixed" post, and he'll simply insert it by his edit.

Comment: @MarounMaroun yes i thought about that, but till yesterday he didn't even knew how to to accept an answer.

Comment: I dont know if there is any system in place to detect collusion that might get you into trouble, but I do think your behavior is very good. (A) You are helping a friend. (B) You are making the site better by editing bad questions. Everybody wins.

Comment: I think it's awesome that you want to help your friend ask better questions. The better solution is once your friend hits 20 reputation (he's 2 away right now), take it to chat. That way no one can say that you're just using your friend to farm reputation.

Comment: It has been answered. I just want to add one thing: I'm a big fan of actually seeing the truth that is right in front of you. If you (where 'you' is addressing your friend) need to ask questions on SO and you don't have the language skill to do so correctly and probably also will have trouble understanding the answers or follow up questions, perhaps it is time to work on your English and get it to a base level.

Comment: *Illegal* lol.  No, it's nice of you.  And I don't think SE considers editing a friend's posts to be rep farming.  Voting them all up, yes, that will get you in trouble, as votes should be indicative of the quality of the post, so gaming these for rep disrupts the system. Now, if your edits are poor, that's another thing.  But you'll just get an edit ban, as you would if you were making poor edits on lots of user's posts.

Comment: I applaud your effort in helping your friend and keeping the quality of the site as high as possible, but I really don't understand why your friend can't do these things himself. SO is not complicated to use so what is it exactly that is preventing you sending him the text and him applying it?

Comment: @DavidG: That's not really "doing these things himself"...

Comment: @BoltClock I mean for the friend to apply the edits. I get that it's difficult to get language and style, especially for a non-English speaker, I'm just suggesting that the friend should be the one who applies the edits. I guess what I'm really trying to ask is what is it that makes it difficult for the friend to make these changes? Is there something particularly difficult/awkward for non-English speakers? Could the site be improved? Or is it just a lack of understanding?

Comment: @DavidG: Oh, that makes more sense. As to your other questions, I'm not sure myself.

Comment: Side note: big edits that require review may get rejected if not approved by OP quickly - giving edit to OP directly to post sound like a bit safer/less questionable route.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

I strongly doubt that you'll draw any attention for this, much less get in any trouble. Systems designed to look for collusion between partners are looking for people who are gaming the system by going after lots of fast, easy points by upvoting each other. People just going in and upvoting their friends' posts doesn't actually add any value to the site at all. In contrast, what you're doing is slow and difficult and *does* add some value, so you're earning those two points per edit.

On top of that, you only have 171 more points to gain with this "scheme," and you're already throttled by the rate at which your friend can post questions. There are easier ways (both honest and dishonest) to gain reputation on Stack Overflow, so I wouldn't worry about getting into too much trouble by helping your friend.

Comment: How far can these systems go to detect people? For example, my development team will sometimes upvote each others' questions if we think they are good enough. Could this sort of thing be detected as reputation farming, despite it just being upvoting a good question that we're all made aware of by a third party source?

Comment: @Joehot200 Yes, if you regularly make a habit of voting for questions by people you know, that can be detected by the systems looking for rep-farming. I'd try to avoid doing it too much.

Answer (score 10):

I know from other posts on Meta that sometimes coworkers end up in trouble on SO because they interact too much and it is perceived as collusion on the part of algorithms or the community. I don't know at what point you can get into trouble.

**However**, in your case here you could just edit the questions *before* they are posted on SO. There's no problem whatsoever with doing this.

Comment: Edit one question a day could get me in trouble ? Just curious.

Comment: As I said "I don't know at what point you can get into trouble." There are the tools that SO employees use to find sock puppets. I don't know how they work. And then there's the community, which is probably more fickle than the tools. Some sock puppet networks are found by users who just notice ongoing interaction between users.

Comment: Sounds like the OP is acting as a [mentor](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/262292/158100) without having the privileges. I don't think it is bad or should be frowned upon...

Comment: @rene I'm telling the OP what an absolutely safe way to help is. I'm not saying that what the OP is doing is bad.

Comment: @Louis oops, that is not how my comment should be read. It wasn't meant to suggest that you claim something bad is going on at all, sorry.

Answer (score 7):

It's perfectly fine to improve bad posts, but I'd recommend you talk to your friend and review his question **before** he posts it to improve his initial reception. You could work on his question asking skills, and try to wean him off of dependence on you.

Nevertheless, the StackOverflow platform will gladly accept your edits on the site and wants to thank you for your efforts by awarding you 2 rep points (until you hit 2000). The system works, and everyone wins in this situation.

Comment: "StackOverflow platform will gladly accept your edits", indeed, but roboreviewers could just as easily reject them all!

Comment: That's why we have audits, if I'm not mistaken... system still works!

Comment: @AaronHall: There are (currently, for technical reasons; [I have a suggestion to change that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267165/add-more-and-better-audits-to-suggested-edits-by-drawing-from-maximally-unanimo)) no suggested edit audits that must be *approved* to pass. All audits can be passed by rejecting.

Comment: I don't like this suggestion. The (limited) wikiness of posts supersedes external collaborative editing software.

Answer (score 6):

**Yes, this is fine.**

You are not cheating.

Your edits are just as valuable to the site as they would be if you did not know the original author.

Keep on keeping on, and thanks for your contributions!

Answer (score 2):

Why would this be cheating or a problem at all?

In my eyes you're trying to help your friend in a way you actually can help. Forget those 2 points you get, you helping your friend without knowing the answer for his problem by making the question readable for people who CAN give a solution to his problem.

If you still feel bad doing this you can do what @AaronHall said above.